# Problems configuring DB2 CLI/ODBC System DSN ODBC Data Source Administrator

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, odbc, db2, dsn

I am trying to create a System DSN ODBC connection to a DB2 9.5 database, but I am getting a very strange problem.

I've looked through the internet and found the following page that has some instructions on how I should proceed: http://www.ryslander.com/how-to-install-and-configure-db2-odbc-driver/.

I followed these instructions and I am able to create a new System DSN, however when I try to configure it it seems as if my configurations don't work at all. For example, when I click on the "Configure" button on my System DSN and I add a TCP/IP protocol configuration on the "Advanced Settings" tab and click "Ok", no errors appear, but when I click on "Configure" again my TCP/IP setting has vanished.

This happened to all my other configurations, such as database name, username, password etc.

Could you help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

Note: my user is in the administrator group and I am using a Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise x64.

**UPDATE**

I managed to create a User DSN and connect to the database. However the problem with the System DSN remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is *far* easier to use the built in DB2 commands to set up DSNs, as long as you aren't afraid of the command line.  Open a DB2 Command Window, and then:

1. `db2 catalog tcpip node n1 remote <hostname or ip> server <port number>`
2. `db2 catalog database <database> at node n1`  (where `n1` is the node name from step 1)
3. `db2 catalog system odbc data source <database>`

Comment: Hi, I am not afraid of the command line :-), but to do this I would need a client program installed and not just the ODBC/CLI driver, right?

Comment: True, but the instructions you referenced showed downloading the full DB2 client.  You installed only Data Server Driver for ODBC/CLI?

Comment: I think so, I have only one driver package called: v9.5fp10_nt32_odbc_cli. Maybe I should download the whole client then. But it is still very strange that I can create a User DSN and not a System DSN even though my user is an Administrator.

Comment: Hi I installed the full client: v9.5fp10_nt32_rtcl (downloaded from: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27016878) and I was able to execute these commands. They worked just fine and my System DSN ODBC is up and running. Thank you again for the help!